# Nestjs early return in interceptor sends [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]

Tags: express, http-headers, nestjs

I am using interceptor on a controller to feed mock data if user is tagged as a demo user in the jwt

It works fine, mock data are fed to client and request doesn't reach my controller, but I still get following error in console :
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

This is my interceptor :

```
@Injectable()
export class UserPageStatsInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    // Let controller handle request
    if (!isDemo(context)) {
      return next.handle();
    }

    // Feed mock datas
    const res = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();

    res.status(200).send('Demo data');
  }
}
```

And here is my controller :

```
@Get('statistics')
  @UseInterceptors(UserPageStatsInterceptor)
  getUsersGlobalStatistics(
    @Headers() headers: CustomHeaders,
    @Query() filters: BasicFiltersDTO,
    @Req() req,
  ): Promise<UserStatisticsDTO> {
    return 'Real data';
  }
```

I suspect that after my `UserPageStatsInterceptor` the request continues somewhere in the internal of nestjs framework but I haven't been able to find out where.
I have tried adding a `return`or `res.end()` at the end but it doesn't change anything.

Note that this only happens when making queries on my frontend client and doesn't happen in postman

Thank you in advance guys !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `res.send()` inside of your interceptor, why not just return an observable that has the data you want to return?

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserPageStatsInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    // Let controller handle request
    if (!isDemo(context)) {
      return next.handle();
    }

    return of('Demo data');
  }
}
```

This will let Nest still handle the response, and not get in the way of actually running your service code.